# Can't start Appium with AppiumServiceBuilder()

Tags: c#, appium, winappdriver

I've found other threads on this, but none of the solutions have worked for me. I'm getting the error below when trying to start Appium using AppiumServiceBuilder()

Error:
OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.Exceptions.InvalidServerInstanceException: 'Invalid server instance exception has occurred: There is no installed nodes! Please install  node via NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium#using-node-js) or download and install Appium app (http://appium.io/downloads.html)'

I'm initializing the AppiumLocalService like this:

```
Public AppiumLocalService appiumLocalService = AppiumServiceBuilder().Build();
```

It fails on that same line

- I've confirmed that nodejs is installed
- I've added the nodejs path to the Path environment variable
- I've confirmed that Appium is installed (via NPM)
- I'm able to start Appium from CMD
- The same code runs on another Windows machine, so it must be something related to setup?

Expected:
The Appium service should start

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the path to the Node.js executable, the Appium JavaScript file, and other options as shown in below

```
    AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(
                        new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                        .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/bin/node"))
                        .withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"))
                        .withLogFile(new File("/path/to/Documents/logs.txt"))  // Change to the absolute path
                        .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOCAL_TIMEZONE));
```